# OKI C911 thinks SRA3 is Tabloid Extra

Tags: windows, laser-printer

I'm printing onto SRA3 on my C911, and it thinks it's Tabloid Extra.  The size of SRA3 (450 x 320mm) is quite different to the size of Tabloid Extra (12" x 18").

So when I put in SRA3 paper, and tell the printer driver (in Windows) that I'm printing to SRA3, then it complains that I must load SRA3, and I have to hit the OK button on the printer to make it print.

If I tell windows I'm printing on Tabloid Extra, it doesn't complain, it just prints, but the margins are then wrong since they are about 1/2" different in width and height.

I tried overriding the paper size on the tray (e.g. to not use the paper size detection) but it doesn't have an option for SRA3.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Are you loading SRA3 in the bypass tray? Most printers can be told from the front panel or web i/f) what size paper is in the bypass tray - can yours?

Comment: nope just tray 1, it's supposed to be good for SRA3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ["User Manual Basic"](http://www.oki.com/me/printing/support/user-manual/colour/45878804/) on page 88 says that A3Wide is not detected when installed in the tray. Instead, it must be set from the printer's control panel. This is different from the Windows settings.

You are getting the message because Windows requests SRA3 (A3Wide), but the printer is not aware it has that paper installed. Tabloid Extra is detected from the tray settings, so if you select that in Windows, the driver and printer settings match and there is no problem.

Page 88 also says that setting the printer's paper size from the Control Panel is shown on page 93. However, pg 93 only talks about the Multi-purpose Tray, so have a look on your printer to see if you can select A3Wide for the tray

Comment: Hi, it's not clear what the size of "A3 Wide" is, in some places it seems to be 12" x 18" or even 13" x 19", which SRA3 most definitely is not (SRA3 is 12.6" x 17.7").  I can't find any mention of SRA3 anywhere in the printer menus, but it's in their sales documentation.  I can set a custom size with mm X&Y but was hoping there would be a setting to tell the printer to properly measure the paper.  Thanks for tracking down the manual reference though.

Comment: Looks like according to that printer manual, A3 Wide is 320 x 450 mm, so that's actually SRA3.  I'm picking "A3 Wide" is not a standardized name/size.

Comment: Yes, Oki's name for SRA3 is A3Wide